# Finding user interactions on Facebook page through Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Given a Facebook user id and a Facebook page id, is there any way to get find all interaction that user has done on the page (posting comments, liking posts etc) without first downloading the entire feed?

I have access key for the page and if necessary I can get one for the user.

For example on the page 315390295169855 (Ninja Saga page) user ID 100002190613755 has written a comment on the post 315390295169855_401357983239752. I would like to search that page so that such interactions could be found.

**Things I have tried**

I tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/315390295169855/feed?q=100002190613755&access_token=FOO
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick.

I have also considered first downloading the entire feed and then searching through it. However it turns out to be impractical, as for example the Ninja Saga page has tens of thousands of interactions and would likely cause the user to start playing farmville instead of waiting for the megabytes-long pre-search download to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer there - pull the list of comments from the Posts you retrieve on the `/feed` connection of the page - i think the default return from a call to `/feed` includes a small number of the recent comments on each Post too, and you can retrieve the rest with a call to `/POST_ID/comments`

Comment: Well, I wanted to show the user all the interaction they have done with the page and if it requires downloading the whole feed then I suppose that wouldn't be practical.